# Strange things in taking width from class and id

Tags: html, css

So there is simple site  there : [JsFiddle link!](http://jsfiddle.net/kppTt/2/) and what is hard to udnerstand for me why those code dosnt equal to : [Another jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/eaxFU/)

The only thing changed between those 2 links are : in #2 there is

```
#panel{
    width:100%;
min-width: 960px;
}
```

in first the same code is in

```
    960f{

width:100%;
    min-width: 960px;
}
```

but it doesnt read it from class. Im confused. What u think about it? Its waste of code to write to every panelI want to be width 100% and min 960px in every div id - its better to use same class each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class names can't begin with numbers. It can begin only with dash, underscore or a letter. See [here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)

(And I guess that if the first character is a dash, the second must be letter or underscore.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start a class name with a number like that.

> "In CSS2, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [A-Za-z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters 161 and higher, plus the hyphen (-); they cannot start with
>   a hyphen or a digit."

Quote from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/).